# Annotating unmodifiable collections

Tags: android, annotations

In my SDK, I want to let users know that a list they are receiving should not be modified. Are there any annotation options for this, or can this only be in the documentation?

Comment: I don't think there is an annotation to do this. So, I would just add "Immutable" to the class name to make it clear.. If you can't change the class name then I think documentation is the best option you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Checker Framework for this https://checkerframework.org/